# "Unable to find a medium containing a live file system"

Tags: busybox

I've installed Ubuntu on my laptop, but when I open Ubuntu, it says the following message (initramfs) Unable to find a medium containing a live file system

Can anyone help?

Comment: - Make sure the md5sum on your iso image is correct ( https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM ) 

- Change the SATA controller type from IDE to AHCI (BIOS setting) if set to IDE and you use a SATA controller.

Answer (score 2):

The same thing happened to me. I was installing Ubuntu from a DVD that I burned, using directions from the Ubuntu web site. My computer kept giving me that error message until I left the DVD in the computer, and then Ubuntu loaded.  But to make it load permanently, and stay on your computer, you have to click on the Install Ubuntu" icon that will appear on your desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem.I was using windows OS.My system did not recognize the type of the file I downloaded(The ISO file of Ubuntu). It was showing it as a zip file.So I clicked on it and changed the way I wanted it to be opened(you can right click on it and press open with and choose it to be known as an ISO file always). I have done this and it was successful.Now I am typing this text from Ubuntu. Good luck!